# SQLite add column, keep data

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database with 4 columns:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASENAME + " (name TEXT, latitude REAL, longitude REAL, country TEXT);");
}
```

Now I want to add another column, but keep the rows that are already in the database. How should I do this? I can't find any useful references to this.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
    //What to do here?
}
```

**EDIT**

I have modified my onCreate to:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASENAME + " (name TEXT, latitude REAL, longitude REAL, country TEXT, code TEXT);");
}
```

and my onUpgrade to:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
    Logger.log("Updating userstations database from " + arg1 + " to " + arg2 + ".");
    if (arg1 == 2 && arg2 == 3) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + DATABASENAME + " ADD COLUMN code TEXT;");
    } else if(arg1 == 1){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASENAME);
    }
    onCreate(db);
}
```

However, now I get this stacktrace:

```
10-01 21:24:19.581: ERROR/Database(21434): Failure 1 (table userstations already exists) on 0x19c378 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE userstations (name TEXT, latitude REAL, longitude REAL, country TEXT, code TEXT);'.
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434): Couldn't open userstations for writing (will try read-only):
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table userstations already exists: CREATE TABLE userstations (name TEXT, latitude REAL, longitude REAL, country TEXT, code TEXT);
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1763)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.databases.UserStationsOpenHelper.onCreate(UserStationsOpenHelper.java:25)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.databases.UserStationsOpenHelper.onUpgrade(UserStationsOpenHelper.java:36)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:132)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.databases.UserStationsOpenHelper.getStations(UserStationsOpenHelper.java:43)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.Data.readUserStations(Data.java:369)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.Data.getUserStations(Data.java:210)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.stationstab.StationsActivity.newStations(StationsActivity.java:190)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.stationstab.StationsActivity.refresh(StationsActivity.java:129)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.stationstab.StationsActivity.onCreate(StationsActivity.java:108)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1598)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.stationstab.StationsActivityGroup.onCreate(StationsActivityGroup.java:38)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1598)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:654)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:216)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.TreinVerkeer.setupTab(TreinVerkeer.java:131)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.TreinVerkeer.initTabs(TreinVerkeer.java:108)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.TreinVerkeer.onCreate(TreinVerkeer.java:62)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
10-01 21:24:19.611: ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(21434):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 21:24:19.621: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(21434): Shutting down VM
10-01 21:24:19.621: WARN/dalvikvm(21434): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4018a560)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.myapp/com.myapp.myapp.TreinVerkeer}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.myapp/com.myapp.myapp.stationstab.StationsActivityGroup}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.myapp/com.myapp.myapp.stationstab.StationsActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 2 to 3: /data/data/com.myapp.myapp/databases/userstations
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.myapp/com.myapp.myapp.stationstab.StationsActivityGroup}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.myapp/com.myapp.myapp.stationstab.StationsActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 2 to 3: /data/data/com.myapp.myapp/databases/userstations
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1598)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:654)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:216)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.TreinVerkeer.setupTab(TreinVerkeer.java:131)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.TreinVerkeer.initTabs(TreinVerkeer.java:108)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.TreinVerkeer.onCreate(TreinVerkeer.java:62)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     ... 11 more
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.myapp/com.myapp.myapp.stationstab.StationsActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 2 to 3: /data/data/com.myapp.myapp/databases/userstations
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1598)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.stationstab.StationsActivityGroup.onCreate(StationsActivityGroup.java:38)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     ... 22 more
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't upgrade read-only database from version 2 to 3: /data/data/com.myapp.myapp/databases/userstations
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:199)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp.databases.UserStationsOpenHelper.getStations(UserStationsOpenHelper.java:43)
10-01 21:24:19.641: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21434):     at com.myapp.myapp
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Please see [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) page for the syntax to create a new column on a table. Basically it is:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN mycolumn TEXT
```

In your onUpgrade method, it would look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String upgradeQuery = "ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN mycolumn TEXT";
    if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2)
         db.execSQL(upgradeQuery);
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling onCreate() afterwards? Upgrade implies that onCreate() has already been called (meaning the tables/db is already created). The problem is detailed in the exception (even down to the line number - Line 25 in onCreate()). You are attempting to create a table that already exists.

Comment: Ah, ok. But I have the line where I delete the db after update from version 1, do I need to call the onCreate then?

Comment: No - do not call onCreate(), get rid of the "else if (oldVersion == 1) {... } code. Now if the old ver is 2 and new ver is 3, then it will update your table name. Also you seem to be confused on database name and table name. You are saying create a table named DATABASENAME. You aren't creating a database, you are creating a table in a database.

Answer (score 6):

**A better approach**

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    switch (oldVersion) {
        case 1:
            db.execSQL(SQL_MY_TABLE);


        case 2:
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN myNewColumn TEXT");

    }
}
```

Lets say in case 1, you upgraded to db version 2.  You created a new table but forgot the myNewColumn you will see in case 2.  What this will do is if you change the db version to 3, case 2 will get ran if its upgrading from 2 to 3.

Comment: In version 3 not case 2nd query, redundant querys in case3.

Comment: This on onUpgrade that shows when the old version is version 2 so the new version would be version 3 and it would run the code.  This code is correct and works.

Comment: The only issue I see with this code is that you should remove all breaks from the switch statement (and make sure all cases are in ascending order), so that all cases below the oldVersion case are also executed.

Comment: Updated my answer.. Thanks @TheIT

Comment: Removing break from case 1 is unnecessary, that is the job of `onCreate` method. `onUpgrade` will get invoke only if the database existed prior to the new version, hence executing a query similar to this: `"CREATE TABLE IF EXISTS ..."` will do not effect.

Answer (score 2):

I have not worked with android, but sqlite provides 'alter table' as most SQL implementations does:

[SQLite alter table](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

Comment: ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN MyNewCol TEXT;

Answer (score 0):

The right way to add new column to DB, for example in version 2, would be:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
         db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN mycolumn TEXT");
    }
}
```

It covers all pitfalls, including major issue with the selected answer: if a user goes from version 1 to 3 they will miss the upgrade query completely! These users will be in an awkward limbo where they are missing a few of the intermediate updates and do not have the expected sql schema.

Also don't forget to alter the create statement adding new column.